# Invariant Violation with static text plus state value in OPTION tag content

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can somebody tell me why this state change generates an error in React when I render it in a  SELECT tag. I get a Invariant Violation error. I don't see any changes in the DOM thats being done by the browser that the error suggests. I ended up using the dangerouslySetInnerHTML method to make this work. Thanks for any input.

Here's the code that throws the error when the state value changes:

```
 <select>
        <option value="0" defaultValue>Add a {this.state.filtertype}</option>
 </select>
```

This code works fine:

```
 <select>
        <option value="0" defaultValue>{this.state.filtertype}</option>
 </select>
```

Static text with evaluated state values as inner html content works fine in other elements?  Is this a React bug?

Comment: I had this same issue, I wish React gave a more specific error as it was hard to track down exactly what was causing the Invariant Violation error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a React bug, it's just more of a limitation of the html `<option>` tags.

So how React updates the DOM is that it essentially converts all floating text nodes to `<span>` tags with a specific reactid, and when a state/prop gets changed, it can easily find those items to reconcile and update if needed.

The problem here is that `<option>` tags cannot contain any other tags. It's invalid HTML and it just doesn't work. Hence the problem is that you're wanting to create a virtual DOM structure like this:

```
<select>
    <option>
        <span>Add a</span>
        <span>filterType</span> <!-- React only wants to change this on update -->
    </option>
</select>
```

When the state updates, React want to simply look for the span id just containing the state and update it. But instead, your browser creates something like this:

```
<select>
    <option>Add a filterType</option>
</select>
```

When React goes to update, it's looking at that `<option>` and wondering where the `<span>` went (since it just wants to change the filterState). Instead it finds nothing, and throws an error.

How to solve it? The easiest way is just prefixing your state with an "Add a " like this in your `render`:

```
<select>
    <option value="0" defaultValue>{"Add a " + this.state.filterType}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks, I know this was answered a while ago and I just wanted to give you credit.